# php form validation required fields

Tags: php

I have a php form that i'm trying to make required fields for but I cannot seem to get it to work right and I know its something i'm missing. I just need to make the form require $name $bank $email and $phone.

```
<?php
    /* Set e-mail recipient */
    $myemail  = "email@email.com";


    /* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
    $name = check_input($_POST['name'], "Enter your name");
    $bank    = check_input($_POST['bank'], "Enter your name");
    $email    = check_input($_POST['email']);
    $phone  = check_input($_POST['phone']);
    $headphones = check_input($_POST['headphones']);
    $subject = "Allied Affiliated Funding - Bose Landing Page Form Submission";
    /* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
    {
        show_error("E-mail address not valid");
    }

    /* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
    $message = "Hello!



    Your contact form has been submitted by:

    Name: $name
    Bank: $bank
    E-mail: $email
    Phone: $phone
    Head Phones: $headphones

    End of message
    ";

    /* Send the message using mail() function */
    mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

    /* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
    if($_POST['headphones'] == Yes){ 
        header("Location: landing1/thank-you-bose.html"); 
    } 
    else { 
        header("Location: landing1/thank-you.html"); 
    }  
    exit();

    /* Functions we used */
    function check_input($data, $problem='')
    {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
        {
            show_error($problem);
        }
        return $data;
    }

    function show_error($myError)
    {
    ?>
        <html>
        <body>

        <b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
        <?php echo $myError; ?>

        </body>
        </html>
    <?php
    exit();
    }
    ?>
```

I have looked at several different tutorials on how to complete this but none of the solutions seem to be working.

Comment: You need to provide a message for `$email` and `$phone`, otherwise your validation function doesn't show an error.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this more?

Comment: You have `if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)` before you show the error. So when you call `check_input()` with no second argument, it won't show the error.

Comment: so do i need to move that line up above or ? little help please.

Comment: I think you need to call it with an argument: `check_input($_POST['email'], "Enter an email")`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is at this line

```
   if($_POST['headphones'] == Yes){
```

It needs to be

```
   if($_POST['headphones'] == "Yes"){
```

You dont have a variable named Yes so i think you want to check if the content of headphones is "yes".